# AngularJS scope.$on setting scope not reflected in UI

Tags: angularjs

The following code works as expected and the scope.checked value is reflected in the UI normally

```
.directive('comparisonSlider',
    function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/app/reports/comparison-slider.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
                $scope.checked = false;
                $rootScope.$on('compare',
                        function () {
                            $scope.checked = true;
                        },
                        true);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

but the following code also works, but the changes to scope aren't reflected in the UI.

```
.directive('comparisonSlider',
    function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/app/reports/comparison-slider.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
                $scope.checked = false;
                $rootScope.$on('compare',
                        function () {
                            $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
                        },
                        true);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try $log.info($scope.checked) in function. You may need to inject $log service

Comment: you haven't provided a lot of info to go on, but `$scope.checked` creates `checked` as a primitive property on `$scope`, which is subject to JavaScript Inheritance issues. This includes problems with using inside `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`, `ng-if`, or other similar directives, which means the problem may be in your HTML.  If `checked` was an object, or in the case of your answer, a property on an object (the controller), then it's not subject to Inheritance problems.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected, not sure why the other one doesn't

```
.directive('comparisonSlider',
    function () {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/app/reports/comparison-slider.html',
            controllerAs: 'sliderCtrl',
            controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
                var self = this;
                self.checked = false;
                $rootScope.$on('compare',
                        function () {
                            self.checked = !self.checked;
                        },
                        true);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
self.checked = !self.checked;
```

to:

```
self.checked = false;
```